# Javascript : Detect duplicate value in array and delete the first one if only one field changes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to transform this array in Javascript :

```
[{"catalog_ref":"OFFER230","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER231","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER235","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER236","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":5}]
```

To this array :

```
[{"catalog_ref":"OFFER230","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER231","level_order":4},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER235","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER236","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":5},
 {"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":5}]
```

I've tried a lot of things and I didn't find a solution. Can someone help me ? I need to keep this order in the new array

Comment: delete the first one or keep the last one if more then 2 objects exist with the same catalog_ref

Comment: hi redu, do you have an example in javascript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `forEach`

```js
var ar = [{"catalog_ref":"OFFER230","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER231","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER235","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER236","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":5}];
var result = [];

ar.forEach(function(e) {
  if (!this[e.catalog_ref]) {
    this[e.catalog_ref] = e;
    result.push(this[e.catalog_ref]);
  }
  this[e.catalog_ref].level_order = e.level_order;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one does the job by eliminating the dupes and keeping the last object (overwriting the previous)

```js
var data = [{"catalog_ref":"OFFER230","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER231","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER235","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER236","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":5}],
    hash = data.reduce((p,c) => (p[c.catalog_ref] = c,p),{});
  result = Object.keys(hash).map(k => hash[k]);
console.log(result)
```

And i think a more appropriate way of doing the same job is utilizing the Map object as follows;

```js
var data = [{"catalog_ref":"OFFER230","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER231","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":4},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER235","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER236","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER232","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER233","level_order":5},{"catalog_ref":"OFFER234","level_order":5}],
  result = [...data.reduce((p,c) => p.set(c.catalog_ref,c),new Map()).values()];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myArray = [{
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER230",
  "level_order": 4
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER231",
  "level_order": 4
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER232",
  "level_order": 4
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER233",
  "level_order": 4
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER234",
  "level_order": 4
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER235",
  "level_order": 5
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER236",
  "level_order": 5
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER232",
  "level_order": 5
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER233",
  "level_order": 5
}, {
  "catalog_ref": "OFFER234",
  "level_order": 5
}]

myArray.reverse();
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    if (myArray[i].catalog_ref == myArray[j].catalog_ref) {
      myArray.splice(j, 1);
      j--;
    }
  }
}
myArray.reverse();
console.log(myArray);
```

Please try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) for looping backwards and build an array with the wanted order.

```js
var data = [{ "catalog_ref": "OFFER230", "level_order": 4 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER231", "level_order": 4 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER232", "level_order": 4 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER233", "level_order": 4 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER234", "level_order": 4 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER235", "level_order": 5 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER236", "level_order": 5 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER232", "level_order": 5 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER233", "level_order": 5 }, { "catalog_ref": "OFFER234", "level_order": 5 }],
    result = data.reduceRight(function (temp) {
        return function (r, a) {
            if (temp[a.catalog_ref]) {
                return r;
            }
            temp[a.catalog_ref] = true;
            return [a].concat(r);
        }
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```